# Under what circumstance these two integrals are equal?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

What I am keen to know is the relationship between $x_1, y_1$ and $x_2, y_2$ to keep the equality below correct knowing that $N_1 < N_2$ (for the sake of simplicity we can assume $N_2 = a\times N_1$ where $a \in \{2, 3, 4, ...\}$):

$$\int_{\frac{N_1}{x_1+y_1}}^{\frac{N_1}{x_1}} t^{N_1}e^{-t}dt = \int_{\frac{N_2}{x_2+y_2}}^{\frac{N_2}{x_2}} t^{N_2}e^{-t}dt$$

It is obvious that $\frac{x_2}{y_2}$ should be greater than $\frac{x_1}{y_1}$ to keep the equality correct, but I need more details.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried some simple examples, such as $N_1=1$, $N_2=2$, where you can easily compute each integral exactly?

Comment: yes, I just did. I even assumed $x_1 = x_2 = 1$ to make it simple but could not get a closed-form expression.